# Why doesnt look ahead and look behind Regex work in Kotlin?

Tags: regex, kotlin

Example:

```
    // Java
    System.out.println("one;two;th/;ree".split("(?<!/);").length);  // 3

    // Kotlin
    println("one;two;th/;ree".split("(?<!/);").size) // 1
```

How to correct this?

Comment: I suggest matching those substrings with, say, [`[^;\/]+(?:\/;[^;]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/iD7jQ1/1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Kotlin example you're not splitting by a `Regex` but by a `String`.

Try the following:

```
println("one;two;th/;ree".split(Regex("(?<!/);")).size) // 3
```

Comment: Alternatively you could also use the `String.toRegex` extension function which I find a bit more readable: `println("one;two;th/;ree".split("(?<!/);".toRegex()).size)`